# Inner button with `position: absolute` will be placed outside a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

Html:

```
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<table>
<tr>
    <td class="container">
        <button class="del">delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container">
<button class="del">delete</button>
</div>​
```

Css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.del {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
}​
```

Why the button inside a `div` will be placed on the top right corner of the div, but the one inside a `td` will be placed outside the table?

How to fix it?

See active demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Freewind/d6Tug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the display style of a `td`, which is `table-cell`. If you set it to `display:block`, it will work correctly.

Just add `display:block` to your .container style.

As freewind pointed out, it would be better to use `inline-block` if it is supported in your browser for td since td's are usually displayed in a row.

Comment: For a `td`, `inline-block` is better, since `block` will make a `td` hold a whole line.

Answer (score 1):

Giving an element `position:absolute;` places it relative to its containing *block*. Since a table cell is not considered a block container (unlike a `div`), it places it relative to the document body itself. `top:3px;` brings it 3px from the top border of the document and `right:3px;` moves it 3px from the right border.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position